# Get error: invalid combination of opcodes and operands when push bl

Tags: assembly, stack

I get the message `error: invalid combination of opcodes and operands` from nasm when doing

```
push bl
```

This code looks perfectly valid to me so why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2):

There's no `PUSH reg8` instruction on the x86. Push the corresponding 16- or 32-bit register instead (`bx` or `ebx`). See page 4-265 in Intel's Software Developer's Manual Vol 2.

Alternatively you could use `sub` and `mov` to store bytes on the stack if you really need to place a series of bytes on the stack without any space in between them.